# Reading Hard Disk Sectors in C++ on Linux

Tags: c++, linux

How do you read hard disk sectors in C++ with gcc/linux? Is there a standard library that I can use or must something be downloaded? In Windows I can use CreateFile(...) to access raw disk sectors, but I do not know how to do in in Linux.

I am using GCC on Ubuntu LTS 10.4. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The hard disk is just another file (not a "regular file" but a "device file", but still, a file).  Open it the normal way...

```
int fdes = open("/dev/sda1", O_RDONLY);
if (fdes < 0)
    err(1, "/dev/sda1");
... do more ...
```

You will get permission errors unless you have the right permissions.  Note that `"/dev/sda1"` is just an example, it is the first partition on disk `sda`, the exact path will depend on your system.  You can list mount points with the `mount` command, and you can access entire disks (instead of just partitions) using `/dev/sda`, `/dev/sdb`, etc.

You could also open it as a C++ `fstream` or C `FILE`, but I do not recommend this.  You will have a better time finding example code and getting help on forums if you use `open` instead.

Comment: `/dev/sda1` would be a partition... for raw drive access you'd probably want to use `/dev/sda`

Comment: +1 for "just another file" and not messing with `dd`. Be wary of permissions, you'll probably either need to be a member of the disk group or root (not a great idea) to do this.

Comment: That this will be very helpful.

Answer (score 12):

As others have correctly pointed out, disk access on Linux (and other Unix-like operating systems) is via a device special file. On my Ubuntu laptop, my hard drive is named "/dev/sda".

Since you specifically ask how to do it in C++ (not merely how to do it in Linux), here is how to read one sector using `std::ifstream`.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <cerrno>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  // Which disk?
  char diskName[] = "/dev/sda";
  std::string diskError = std::string() + diskName + ": ";

  // Open device file
  std::ifstream disk(diskName, std::ios_base::binary);

  if(!disk)
    throw(std::runtime_error(diskError + std::strerror(errno)));

  // Seek to 54321'th sector
  disk.seekg(512 * 54321);
  if(!disk)
    throw(std::runtime_error(diskError + std::strerror(errno)));

  // Read in one sector
  std::vector<char> buffer(512);
  disk.read(&buffer[0], 512);
  if(!disk)
    throw(std::runtime_error(diskError + std::strerror(errno)));
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to acquire the sector size for a disk?

Comment: @PatrikNusszer - maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416241/block-device-information-without-mounting-in-linux

Answer (score 1):

you can dump disk sectors to a file with the dd command and read the file generated