# Block device information without mounting in Linux

Tags: linux, block-device

I am trying to get some information (specifically block size) of block device in linux, in C++. Is it possible to get block size of a device without mounting it and possibly without looking into dynamic files (like the ones in `/sys`), but with a system call only.

I was trying with `stat`, but it returns data about `/dev` filesystem if I ask about `/dev/sdb2`.

If it's impossible with system call, where should i look in dynamic files (haven't been able to locate it either.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to use [`ioctl`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ioctl), in particular `BLKSSZGET`.

Quoting linux/fs.h:

```
#define BLKSSZGET  _IO(0x12,104)/* get block device sector size */
```

Untested example:

```
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>

int fd = open("/dev/sda");
size_t blockSize;
int rc = ioctl(fd, BLKSSZGET, &blockSize);
```

Comment: oh, may somebosy suggest, why am I getting a zero?

Comment: @shbk - is blockSize zero or rc? Both being zero would be suprising.

Comment: yeah,it was so. I should be more attentive. Thanks.

Comment: For the record: BLKSSZGET = logical block size, BLKBSZGET = physical block size, BLKGETSIZE64 = device size in bytes, BLKGETSIZE = device size/512. At least if the comments in fs.h and my experiments can be trusted.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple block sizes, there's the soft block size, the logical block size, and the physical block size. There's an ioctl (BLKSSZSET) to set the logical block size.

Demo sample (run as root):

```c
#!/usr/bin/tcc -run

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>

int main()
{
  int fd = open("/dev/sda", O_RDONLY);
  unsigned int soft_block_size = 0, logical_block_size = 0, physical_block_size = 0;
  int rcs = ioctl(fd, BLKBSZGET, &soft_block_size);
  int rcl = ioctl(fd, BLKSSZGET, &logical_block_size);
  int rcp = ioctl(fd, BLKPBSZGET, &physical_block_size);
  printf("Soft block size: %u\n", soft_block_size);
  printf("Logical block size: %u\n", logical_block_size);
  printf("Physical block size: %u\n", physical_block_size);
}
```

Error handling omitted for brevity.

On my system I get:

```
Soft block size: 4096
Logical block size: 512
Physical block size: 4096
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the `ioctl` value should rather be `unsigned long` than `size_t` (the latest is more memory related), I would also initialize it to 0  (just in case `BLKSSZGET` returns `unsigned int` instead).

```
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>

int fd = open("/dev/sda");
unsigned long blockSize = 0;
int rc = ioctl(fd, BLKSSZGET, &blockSize);
```

Comment: They're size_t's in `fs.h`, fwiw:  `#define BLKBSZGET  _IOR(0x12,112,size_t)` and `#define BLKBSZSET  _IOW(0x12,113,size_t)`.

Comment: They're `unsigned int` in kernel source though. Implementation calls `put_uint` which does `put_user(val, (unsigned int __user *)arg)`.