# Portable way to determine sector size in Linux

Tags: c, linux, hard-drive, sysfs

I want to write a small program in C which can determine the sector size of a hard disk. I wanted to read the file located in `/sys/block/sd[X]/queue/hw_sector_size`, and it worked in CentOS 6/7.

However when I tested in CentOS 5.11, the file `hw_sector_size` is missing, and I have only found `max_hw_sectors_kb` and `max_sectors_kb`.

Thus, I'd like to know how can I determine (APIs) the sector size in CentOS 5, or is there an other better way to do so. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Block device information without mounting in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8416241/608639)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `fdisk` utility displays this information (and runs successfully on kernels older even than than the 2.6.x vintage on CentOS 5), so that seems a likely place to look for an answer.  Fortunately, we're living in the wonderful world of open source, so all it requires is a little investigation.

The `fdisk` program is provided by the [util-linux](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git) package, so we need that first.

The sector size is displayed in the output of `fdisk` like this:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 477 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

If we look for `Sector size` in the [util-linux](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git) code, we find it in [disk-utils/fdisk-list.c](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git/tree/disk-utils/fdisk-list.c#n65):

```
fdisk_info(cxt, _("Sector size (logical/physical): %lu bytes / %lu bytes"),
            fdisk_get_sector_size(cxt),
            fdisk_get_physector_size(cxt));
```

So, it looks like we need to find `fdisk_get_sector_size`, which is defined in [libfdisk/src/context.c](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git/tree/libfdisk/src/context.c#n912):

```
unsigned long fdisk_get_sector_size(struct fdisk_context *cxt)
{
    assert(cxt);
    return cxt->sector_size;
}
```

Well, that wasn't super helpful.  We need to find out where `cxt->sector_size` is set:

```
$ grep -lri 'cxt->sector_size.*=' | grep -v tests
libfdisk/src/alignment.c
libfdisk/src/context.c
libfdisk/src/dos.c
libfdisk/src/gpt.c
libfdisk/src/utils.c
```

I'm going to start with `alignment.c`, since that filename sounds promising.  Looking through that file for the same regex I used to list the files, we find [this](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git/tree/libfdisk/src/alignment.c#n494):

```
cxt->sector_size = get_sector_size(cxt->dev_fd);
```

Which leads me to:

```
static unsigned long get_sector_size(int fd)
{
    int sect_sz;

    if (!blkdev_get_sector_size(fd, &sect_sz))
        return (unsigned long) sect_sz;
    return DEFAULT_SECTOR_SIZE;
}
```

Which in turn leads me to the definition of `blkdev_get_sector_size` in [lib/blkdev.c](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git/tree/lib/blkdev.c#n201):

```
#ifdef BLKSSZGET
int blkdev_get_sector_size(int fd, int *sector_size)
{
    if (ioctl(fd, BLKSSZGET, sector_size) >= 0)
        return 0;
    return -1;
}
#else
int blkdev_get_sector_size(int fd __attribute__((__unused__)), int *sector_size)
{
    *sector_size = DEFAULT_SECTOR_SIZE;
    return 0;
}
#endif
```

And there we go.  There is a `BLKSSZGET` `ioctl` that seems useful.  A search for `BLKSSZGET` leads us to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416241/block-device-information-without-mounting-in-linux), which includes the following information in a comment:

> For the record: BLKSSZGET = logical block size, BLKBSZGET = physical
>   block size, BLKGETSIZE64 = device size in bytes, BLKGETSIZE = device
>   size/512. At least if the comments in fs.h and my experiments can be
>   trusted. – Edward Falk Jul 10 '12 at 19:33

Comment: This is absolutely amazing! Thanks alot larsks!